# How to reinstall Xorg on fedora 33

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, reinstall

I messed up Xorg & I am unable to resolve errors and I now want to reinstall xorg how do I do this? I tried doing `# dnf groupinstall "X Window System"` But it didn't work.

Comment: Experimenting with systems is a great way to learn, but you’d probably save an awful lot of time recovering from your many breakages if you did it on a non-essential system, *e.g.* in a VM...

Answer (score 2):

X.org related packages don't have their own group in Fedora. You could do this instead:

```
sudo dnf reinstall '*xorg*' 'mesa*' 'libx*' 'libX*' 'fontconfig*'
```

This will **not** overwrite any files in `/etc/X11`, so whatever changes you've made in this directory will persist.

Comment: How do i reset /etc/x11 then?

Comment: `sudo mv /etc/X11 /etc/X11.save` prior to running `dnf reinstall`. Or make use of `*.rpmnew` files

Comment: I have to reinstall whole system?